# Ошибка подключения видео(youtube) в фрагменте

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, youtube-api

Фрагмент:

```
 public class voina_1 extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment implements
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    public static final String API_KEY = "мой ключ сюда не писал";

    //http://youtu.be/<VIDEO_ID>
    public static final String VIDEO_ID = "dKLftgvYsVU";


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.voina_1,container, false);



        /** Initializing YouTube player view **/
        YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                        R.id.youtube_player);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this); // показывает здесь ошибку, код айпи мой там правыльный стоит

    @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult result) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
            /** add listeners to YouTubePlayer instance **/
            player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
            player.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);

            /** Start buffering **/
            if (!wasRestored) {
                player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
            }
        }

        private YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPaused() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPlaying() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopped() {
            }

        };

        private YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAdStarted() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoaded(String arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoading() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onVideoEnded() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onVideoStarted() {
            }
        };
    }
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    >
<fragment
                android:id="@+id/youtube_player"
                android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Ошибка:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                           at com.whitestar.voina.voina_1.onCreateView(voina_1.java:40)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Добавлять фрагмент в разметку, в xml - плохая идея. Добавляйте его программно.
2. Получать фрагмент из фрагментМенеджера в процессе создания его разметки - странная идея.
3. Помещать фрагмент в самого себя - ещё страшнее.
4. NullPointerException возникает когда одна из ваших переменных - `null`

**Итого:**

Вам надо изучить азы явы и андроида, прежде чем пытаться что-то сделать. Иначе вы будете принимать очень неправильные решения и не сможете понять сути своих ошибок. А мы вам тут не сможем их объяснить.

Comment: скажите возможно ли вообще реализовать то что я хочю показ видео с ютуба в фрагменте? что бы я зря время не потратил

Comment: @Андрей, ну, судя по тому, что для этого есть фрагмент то да. Надо просто доки прочитать к нему и сделать так как там написано. Но для этого надо иметь базовые представления о яве и работе с фрагментами как таковыми.

Comment: спасибо) думаю я это сделаю еще не скоро(((